# How to acquire the Key/name of root level JSON Objects with JSONPath?

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

So I have been using [jayway JSONPath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) to query JSON Objects much like the following:

```
{
  "messageHeader" : {

     "sentBy" : "someOne",
     "userName" : "John Doe"
  },

 "payload" : []
}
```

And this is working fine for the most part, except now I wish to select the root level objects using the path $..* and preform separate tasks depending on the type of object present in the message, using their key/names as an identifier. 
However, using said path, or $.* , will always produces a JSONArray much like this:

[{sentBy:someOne,userName:John Doe},[]]

The JSON objects appear to be anonymous, they have no keys. Is there anyway I can access the key for these objects directly as a String? If the data is not present, then why does the path: $.messageHeader.sentBy , work?

Answer (score 1):

From [README](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath/blob/master/README.md) of the JsonPath :

> When evaluating a path you need to understand the concept of when a
>   path is definite. A path is indefinite if it contains:
>
> - .. - a deep scan operator
> - ?() - an expression
> - [,  (, )] - multiple array indexes
>
> **Indefinite paths always returns a list** (as represented by current JsonProvider).

This should explain the above phenomenon.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the effect I desire though?

Comment: I think a better place to ask this questions would be this Google Group : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jsonpath